# Python Tkinter Tk/Tcl usage Problem

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, expect

I am using Tcl from Python Tkinter Module like below

```
from Tkinter import *
Tcl = Tcl().eval
Tcl("info patchlevel") 
'8.3.5'
```

You can see Tcl version 8.3 is selected by python.

But i also have tcl8.4 in my system.
Now,how do i make python select tcl8.4 in Tkinter module.

Tcl8.3 does not have Expect package,so i can not use Expect package in Python Tcl/Tk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the version of Tcl/Tk is used by python is determined at compiling time. So you need to look at the code, recompile python against the version of Tcl/Tk you want to use. Maybe recompiling the _tkinter.so library is enough too, since it's loaded dynamically.